# Select SqlCommand return char

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server, winforms

I have got this part of code which do `SELECT SqlCommand` for `column char(20)` but the result is always returns `0` - this is because I don't know how to improve my code so it would return char(20) - value which is in this column inserted.

```
 SqlCommand sc = new SqlCommand("SELECT doklad FROM netpokl WHERE id_dok=" + newIdentity, spojeni);
 spojeni.Open();

 int id_dok = Convert.ToChar(sc.ExecuteScalar());

 spojeni.Close();

 MessageBox.Show("" + id_dok);

 SqlCommand sc2 = new SqlCommand("UPDATE kliplat set doklad=@doklad WHERE id="+newIdentity, spojeni);
 sc2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@doklad", id_dok);

 spojeni.Open();
 sc2.ExecuteNonQuery();
 spojeni.Close();
```

Would anyone help me improve my code please?

Comment: Not an answer to your question but you really need to read about [SQL injection](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: For Parameter better use ADO.Net Parameter (SqlParameter) no Self-made strings - to Dan's answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SqlCommand sc = new SqlCommand(string.Format("SELECT doklad FROM netpokl WHERE id_dok='{0}'", newIdentity), spojeni);
object obj = sc.ExecuteScalar();
if(obj == null) ; //Should show some message or throw exception
string id_dok = obj.ToString().PadRight(20);
//...
SqlCommand sc2 = new SqlCommand(string.Format("UPDATE kliplat set doklad=@doklad WHERE id='{0}'",newIdentity), spojeni);
//...
```

BTW: I don't think this is needed. In fact you should check if it's length > 20, then the string should be truncated. Your database table should also use `nvarchar(20)` instead.

Comment: Hello I tried this but it gave following ex: Reference to an object isn't set to an instance of an object. Any idea where I make mistake?

Comment: @Marek this code should replace some lines of yours starting from `int id_dok` to the end of that line.

Comment: I replaced that as you said but still receiving the same exceptions, don't have any idea where the mistake is.

Comment: @Marek at which line it highlights?

Comment: At ´string id_dok = obj.ToString().PadRight(20);´

Comment: @Marek it looks like that your `Select` doesn't return any value. So `obj = null`. As I comment, you should handle if it's null.

Comment: @Marek try the `SqlCommand` I updated, your query looks like wrong.

Comment: thank you you were right again my SELECT command was really bad. I edited it and it is working properly. Thank you so much for your time and answer.